# Как преобразовать символ '\' в строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как на Python преобразовать символ `\` в строку? Именно этот символ.

Я использую функцию `os.getcwd()`, но символы `\` так и остаются.

Comment: Какая вообще задача с `getcwd()`? А то теперь выглядит как проблема XY.

Comment: Я уже решил проблему. Оказывается что getcwd() лишь отображает '\' символ но на самом деле он является экранированным. Спасибо за дискуссию

Answer (score 2):

Нужно применить экранирование, т.е. поставить перед ним спецсимвол "\":

```
print("\\")
```

Answer (score -3):

```
str(\, 'UTF-8')
```

1 - что ты хочешь преобразовать в строку, в рамках разумного
2 - кодировка, которая нужна тебе

Comment: Вряд ли SyntaxError является желаемым результатом.